Altera Megafunction DCFIFO not transferring expected written data
I am trying to use Altera DE0-Nano board to transfer the from my chip to PC through the board. Since the data is being generated at a higher rate than it can be transferred by the JTAG chain of the board, therefore, I am using DCFIFO. During testing, I was writing data to DCFIFO by a clock which is generating data a much faster rate and then data is being transferred through JTAG chain. I am considering the Full and Empty signals while writing and reading so that there is no error. But for sure, it is not giving the desired results. Any clue? If more information is needed I will provide it.
Following is the JTAG interface code:
module JTAG_interface (tck, ir_in, v_sdr, data, empty, tdo, rdreq);
input tck, ir_in, v_sdr, data, empty;

output reg tdo;
output reg rdreq = 0;
wire select_DR1 = ir_in; // Data Register 1 will collect the new LED Settings
    
reg flag = 1; // this flag enables the synchronization of data writing
reg [20:0] count_bits = 0; // this register accounts for the number of bits to be sent out

parameter NUM_BITS = 614400; // where 614400 = 320*240*8, that is, the number of bits in an 8-bit QVGA image
 
always @ (negedge tck)
begin               
    if (v_sdr)  // VJI is in Shift DR state
    begin
        if (select_DR1 && count_bits < NUM_BITS) // if ir_in has been set to choose DR1 and we have not sent out all the bits yet
        begin   
            flag <= 1; // this indicates that the first bit of the next data sequence must be assigned to tdo when v_sdr is externally set to 0
            tdo <= data; // we assign to tdo the current bit
            count_bits <= count_bits + 1; // a new bit has been sent out
            rdreq <= 1; // the bit just sent out is acknowledged
        end
        else
        begin
            rdreq <= 0;
        end
    end 
    else
    begin
        if (flag && !empty) // we prepare the first bit of the next data sequence
        begin
            flag <= 0;
            tdo <= data;                                
            count_bits <= 1;
            rdreq <= 1;             
        end             
        else
        begin               
            rdreq <= 0; // only the first bit is acknowledged for the time being        
        end
    end     
end 

endmodule

following is the counter to generate write request and providing data to be written. Dat is available in the negative clock and is written in the positive clock.
module counter (full, data, wrreq, clk);
input full;

output reg [7:0] data;
output reg wrreq = 0;
inout clk;

reg [7:0] counter = 0;

always @ (negedge clk)
begin                   
    if (!full)
    begin
        wrreq <= 1;
        data <= counter;
        counter <= counter + 1;
        if (counter == 253)
        begin
            counter <= 0;
        end
    end
    else
    begin
        wrreq <= 0;
    end
end 

endmodule
